# React Native Expo: Google analitics - unable to get ios to work properly

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-analytics, plist

I have that strange problem I encountered today. On our React Native app we had a working version of google analitics - it worked for both android and ios. It was on test-like account.

Recently, we decided to go for production and had to change firebase account to our client's account. The new config files were generated (plsit, json) and app.json was properly adjusted too.

The strange thing is that after this change everything seems to work on android but ios doesn't work at all on the new firebase acccount. What is even stranger - despite the fact that we have different config files now the analitics are still updating in our test-like account.

What can be the cause of this problem? And why the iOS analitics is sending data to our old account/old project on firebase?